# Forward CURL request on the Fly

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I need to forward `CURL` requests on the fly that is written in php.
a `php` program send request to: XYZ.COM

is there any way to `forward` its `request` to another location ?

can i use `.htaccess` ?

please let me know if there is any solution.

php script is encoded & we dont have access to its source code.
script is web based.

Comment: You want to detect if a request was made from CURL ?
You may catch the User-Agent

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is forward request based on [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent). Since that header can be set freely, there is no way you can 100% assure that you are getting all request coming from a curl client.

Imagine this `cURL` command execution

```
curl --user-agent "freetext" http://www.example.com
```

If you are sending the request yourself you could do

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "myagent");
// ...
// all the other parameters needed 
// taken from http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php
```

the Apache RewriteRule would look like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^myagent$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/curl/$1  [L,302]
```

Comment: if you are sending the curl request your own you can again use your own user agent and forward those request accordingly.